# How can I get all date form selected year?

Tags: php, mysql

My code function is get all value where season from/to in ranges selected years.

I have 2 dropdown for user to select season from/to year . But i have a bug that i can't get value if the tour have both season from/to smaller/larger than selected year . Example:

selected season from/to : 2015 -2016

```
from          to
2011-05-06    2014-11-12 (not get - work)
2012-04-01    2015-12-31 (get - work)
2015-01-01    2016-08-10 (get - work)
2016-08-11    2018-12-28 (get - work)
2017-01-01    2018-01-01 (not get - work)

2014-01-11    2017-01-01 (I want get this too, because my selected year is 2015-2016)
```

My code:

```
$first_day = mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, $params['seasonfrom']) ; //2015-01-01
$first_day = "'".date('Y-m-d',$first_day)."'";

$last_day = mktime(0, 0, 0, 12, 31, $params['seasonto']) ;  //2016-12-31
$last_day = "'".date('Y-m-d',$last_day)."'";

$str1.="(ts.SsnFrom >= {$first_day} AND ts.SsnFrom <={$last_day} 
OR ts.SsnTo >= {$first_day} AND ts.SsnTo <={$last_day})";
```

CAn anyone give me a solution .Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know PHP. Generally suggesting this. This may help you.

```
$str1.="({$first_day} BETWEEN ts.SsnFrom AND ts.SsnTo OR {$last_day} BETWEEN ts.SsnFrom AND ts.SsnTo)";
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment . But It not work ..I checked but it only get 2 season (9-12-2014 -> 28-2-2015 , 01-10-2016 -> 01-01-2017) but my code can get also this ( 01-03-2015 -> 31-05-2015 , 01-09-2015 ->02-01-2016 ,01-05-2016 -> 30-09-2016)

Comment: I tried in my DB, it returned all rows as you expected. See this SQlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bbc556/1

Comment: Thanks . Fixed by add this condition :))
OR (ts.SsnFrom <= {$first_day} AND ts.SsnTo >={$last_day})